# What tool can I use to manage notes and/or bookmarks for a collection of PDF files?

Tags: software-recommendation, pdf, document-management

I am doing some research and I do put lots of notes and bookmarks in the books (PDF files).

I am looking for a tools that will allow me to see and search inside all these notes.

I supposed that this tools should be able to scan a directory with PDF files, for notes and keep them in sync.

Comment: I try to build a comparison matrix at https://spreadsheets.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AuAbgmBsosYRdGFnSWdNOGtNY2lkUlBJZmc1cGxDcEE&hl=en_US

Comment: Your column for BibDesk is mostly wrong. Try using BibDesk + Skim. It lets you organize, search, and see notes.

Answer (score 1):

You should try [Mendelely](http://www.mendeley.com/), a Reference Manager with Dropbox-like sharing/syncing. It reads Comments from PDFs, but sometimes mixes them up. In my example i had saved an Article as a PDF with the Headline as the Filename, but Mendeley indexed my Comment as the Filename.

You should also take a look at [Eaglefiler](http://c-command.com/eaglefiler/), as the name says more Archiv-oriented.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need  [Papers](http://www.mekentosj.com/papers/)

Comment: Sorry, but Papers is not able to recognize standard annotations/notes made with Preview or Adobe Reader. They recognize only their own annotations.

Answer (score 0):

What about [Evernote](https://www.evernote.com).. There may be issues like limited uploaded. But you may go for premium option.